# systemd-timesyncd service

Tags: time, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

I am have mentioned an IP in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` as `NTP=192.168.1.180` and restarted the service through following command `systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd` but I time isn't syncing with server. Following are the logs

```
started Network Time Synchronization.
systemd-timesyncd[8651]: Timed out waiting for reply from 192.168.1.180:123 (192.168.1.180).
systemd-timesyncd[8651]: Timed out waiting for reply from 192.168.1.180:123 (192.168.1.180).
systemd-timesyncd[8651]: Timed out waiting for reply from 192.168.1.180:123 (192.168.1.180).
systemd-timesyncd[8651]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
systemd-timesyncd[8651]: Timed out waiting for reply from 192.168.1.180:123 (192.168.1.180).
systemd-timesyncd[8651]: Timed out waiting for reply from 192.168.1.180:123 (192.168.1.180).
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: Your NTP-server either doesn't work or isn't reachable.

Comment: Before I found your question I've just posted the very similar one here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672579/systemd-timesyncd-timed-out

It's certainly not because server is not reachable, I tried multiple servers with the same result. Let me know if you were able to figure it out.